# Does subterfuge work on ALL networks?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

Does subterfuge's ARP poisoning attack work on *all* networks? If not, what kind of precautions can be taken against it? Meaning, what kind of networks, if any, does it fail on? My understanding is that the only way to fight the attack is to have some sort of CA or web of trust; since wifi and ethernet networks don't have that capability, every network should be vulnerable. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't a silver bullet, for example:

- You are using static ARP entries. This will completely mitigate the risk of ARP spoofing.
- You are using encryption and you are using it properly. The bad guy can sniff your traffic, but he can't do anything with it.

Comment: For encryption, you would need a way of verifying identity, e.g. using a web of trust like I said.

Comment: Indeed, but static ARP is still an option if your network isn't too big

Comment: So basically unless you verify everybody's identity there's no way

Comment: What about networks where you login with a username? Because then when people join you know who they are, so you could set it up so they can't later pretend to be the router.

Comment: You only need to verify the nodes  you want to 'talk' to.

Comment: Only the defender needs the static entries (of the gateway and other servers on the LAN it needs to talk to).

Comment: Ya, I meant "the defender knows who they are"

Comment: First, ensure attackers can't get onto your network.